# Can't create inherited process in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I am new to Azure Devops server and I'm trying to create an inherited process.
my collection is type hosted xml .

I used this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops

But I don't see in my process the option of creating inherited process.

[My Process menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kKc5.png)

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the permissions? how are you the organization owner?

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I have full permissions, i'm working with Azure devops server . after searching i found that my collection is type hosted xml , so i wont be able to do that .

Answer (score 1):

To create, edit, and manage processes, you must be a member of the **[Project Collection Administrators group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-project-collection-level-permissions)**, or have the corresponding permissions **Create process**, **Delete process**, **Edit process**, or **Delete a field from organization** set to **Allow**.

By default, only Project Collection Administrators can create and edit processes. However, these admins can grant permissions to other team members by explicitly setting the **Create process**, Delete process, or Edit process permissions at the collection level for a specific user.

Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops#customize-an-inherited-process) you can refer to .

[image]

[image]

**Update** :

You can't import or define a global list as supported by the Hosted XML and On-premises XML process models. To learn more, see [Define global lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/define-global-lists?view=azure-devops).

> The Inheritance process model doesn't support global lists.

This is stated in this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/inheritance-process-model?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fsettings%2Fwork%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fsettings%2Fwork%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#what-you-cant-customize).

In addition, migration from XML to Inherited is not supported on Azure DevOps Server yet. Please refer to this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/516655/i-cant-see-clone-process-to-inherited-button-in-co.html).

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I have full permissions, i'm working with Azure devops server . after searching i found that my collection is type hosted xml , so i wont be able to do that . now i'm looking for converting my collection from hosted xml to inherited.

Comment: I am afraid that migration from XML to Inherited is not supported on Azure DevOps Server yet.You can refer to this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/761976/cannot-clone-a-hosted-xml-process-to-an-inheritanc.html).

Comment: Unfortunately my company is not ready for that . Thanks for the help